# Can I create a few tables in one table, mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, categories

I have one database with 6 tables.

One of the table is named category and it has 5 or 6 categories in it.

*For example: Movie category that has the comedy, drama, thriller, horror, romance sub categories etc.*

So can I, in the table, add the sub categories, or should I create them like tables?

And if I have a lot of data to add in the database is there any easier way to do it?

I'm working with **xampp**.

Comment: Could you clearify what you mean by sub-categories and how they relate to the categories and/or movie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `categoryOf` field to the `category` tabel, it will be used to store the id of the 'parent category'.

For a sub category use this field to point to the category of which it is a sub category of.
Leave the field empty for (main) category entries

For example:

```
id  name         categoryOf
0   comedy       NULL
1   drama        NULL
2   sub-comedy   0
3   sub-drama    1
4   sub-comedy2  0
```

Note: Using this method, you can even add sub-sub-categories if you like...

Comment: "*Using this method, you can even add sub-sub-categories if you like*" - you can, but because MySQL doesn't support recursive functions it's very difficult to query and maintain.  What if you want to fetch all comedy, including its descendants?  In MySQL, hierarchical data of this sort is often best modelled using nested sets or transitive closure tables.

Comment: The question is about storage and this method still works and is very simple, even with sub-sub-categories. Fetching all of a category and all its sub-categories in one query might be/is impossible/difficult using one query, but doing so in one query is not (yet) required.

Comment: My observation was that, whilst this adjacency list model is simple to write into, it's generally hard to read from.  I was only commenting for others' benefit that alternatives do exist which might be more useful/applicable, depending on one's need.  If one views storage as write-only, then it's questionable what purpose it serves.  :)

Comment: Agree. Although I would change it to 'it's generally hard to read *efficiently* from'. Using PHP to read all required data using multiple queries is not hard (only inefficient)